# How do I Import an RSS feed as Wordpress posts without duplicates?

Tags: rss, wp-insert-post, xml, post-duplication

I have an XML feed url I am now using this code to create new Custom Post Type Posts from an rss feed in my functions.php file:

```
    /*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Schedule and update fashion news with the news rss feed
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| 
| */

if (!wp_next_scheduled('update_feed'))
    wp_schedule_event(current_time('timestamp'), 'hourly', 'update_feed');

add_action('update_feed', 'update_fashion_news');

function update_fashion_news() {
    // retrieve the previous date from database
        $time = get_option('latestpostdate');

        //read the feed
        if(function_exists('fetch_feed')){
            $uri = 'http://www.sitename.com/feed.xml';
            $feed = fetch_feed($uri);
        }

        if($feed) {

            foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item){
                $titlepost = $item->get_title();
                $content = $item->get_content();
                $description = $item->get_description();
                $itemdate = $item->get_date();
                $media_group = $item->get_item_tags('', 'enclosure');
                $img = $media_group[0]['attribs']['']['url'];
                $width = $media_group[0]['attribs']['']['width'];           
                // $latestItemDate = $feed->get_item()->get_date();


                // if the date is < than the date we have in database, get out of the loop
                if( $itemdate <= $time) break;


                // prepare values for inserting

                $post_information = array(
                    'post_title' => $titlepost,
                    'post_content' => $description,
                    'post_type' => 'fashionnews',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );

                wp_insert_post( $post_information );    

            }
        }
        // update the new date in database to the date of the first item in the loop        
        update_option( 'latestpostdate', $feed->get_item()->get_date() );
}
```

[UPDATE: Have updated the code above to move from simple_xml to using simplepie]

[UPDATE2: Have moved the code and wrapped it in a WP schedule event as advised by @Mridul below]

I am still checking to see if my code works when the next batch of news updates arrive. Does anyone think this code wouldn't work for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RSS feed has all the items in a fixed order(latest to oldest). In this case you can save the date & time of the last post you created, as an option & when you read the feed again, you can check the time previously saved to know which of the posts in the feed are new & insert them, then update the time again

The functions you're interested in are `update_option`, `get_option` & `wp_insert_post`. You can find the reference for each of them in the wordpress codex, just google it. The flow would go like this

```
// retrieve the previous date from database
$time = get_option('mylastfeeddate');

// include the code to read the xml file here &
// then the foreach loop as you did in the question
foreach($items as $item) {

    // if the date is < than the date we have in database, get out of the loop
    if( $item->pubDate < $time) break;

    // assign the values in the format of wp_insert_post()
    $out = array();

    // insert the post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $out );

}

// update the new date in database to the date of the first item in the loop
update_option( 'mylastfeeddate', $items[0]->pubDate );
```

**UPDATE**

For making the code execute after some fixed time frame use wordpress cron functions like this

```
if (!wp_next_scheduled('update_feed'))
    wp_schedule_event(current_time('timestamp'), 'hourly', 'update_feed');

add_action('update_feed', 'function_name');
function function_name() {
    // here goes all the code to read the feed
}
```

change `hourly` to the time you like here is the codex reference  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

For adding custom time frames

```
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'new_cron_schedules');
function new_cron_schedules($schedules) {
    array_merge($schedules, array('two_hourly' => array( 'interval' => 7200, 'display' => __('Twice Hourly') )));
}
```

After this filter for eg. you can replace 'hourly' above to 'two_hourly'

Comment: Good idea! I was thinking of checking if post title exists in database and then inserting the post. Can you tell me how I can  'save the date & time of the last post you created, as an option'?

Comment: updated the answer above with more details

Comment: Ok I am gonna give this a shot

Comment: I have updated the post above with the code you have shown me but I still get duplicates. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the if condition, try `<=` & also use `strtotime` (`DateTime::createFromFormat` if your php version supports it) to both the dates in the if condition

Comment: I think `<=` did the trick. But I tried this before too but it didn't work with key that was cached in the options table. Did it malfunction because of the cached value? 


So I updated the key now and tried again and now it seems to work.

Let me do some further testing and I will markt this as the correct answer. Thanks for sticking through with me for this. Appreciate it!

Comment: one reason i can think of for malfunction is that the first time you run this code there's no date value saved in the database(get_option returns null). Also you should do a check for `$feed` just before `foreach`, in case `$feed` isn't initialised or if there are 0 items

Comment: Good Tip! A little more advice if you please: I want to make sure that this code only runs once every 6 hours. So Should I move everything to functions.php? What kind of hook should I use? Should I use `Wp_Cron` or the `transients` api?

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: this is great. I have updated my code above. Does it look alright? Do you think this will work? I can't check if this is working or not unless the next batch of fresh updates arrive in an hour.

Comment: i couldn't see any error in it, but still keep an eye out just in case. Also the event is scheduled only after the `wp_schedule_event` is executed, so you'll have to refresh the page once before the timer gets activated

Comment: Thanks for the check @Mridul. I have refreshed the page. My fingers are now crossed :)